# Need Mulesoft Development Fundamentals training material

Tags: mule-studio

Does anyone have the Mulesoft Development Fundamentals course ppt?

This is the course link : https://training.mulesoft.com/instructor-led-training/mulesoftu-fundamentals

I had completed it, but I want to refer to the ppts once. The course content ppts..

Thanks,
Narasimhan.

Answer (score 0):

goto this link : https://training.mulesoft.com/instructor-led-training/mulesoftu-fundamentals

this is an 8 weeks program and you can do certification and claim points from champions program